# How to save data to mssql with js on asp.net pages?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sql-server, save, instagram

I get some info from instagram via its api with js. By the way, my site is written with asp.net. How can I save them to my database?

Data comes like this:

```
$ 
for (var i = 0; i < data["data"].length; i++) {
  $("#PhotosUL").append("<li style='float:left;list-style:none;'><a target='_blank' href='" + data.data[i].link + "'><img src='" + data.data[i].images.thumbnail.url + "'></img></a></li>");
}
```

Comment: You tagged Instagram, but it does not really related. Also, how's your DB schema? Last, please differentiate client-side & server-side scripting. The above codes are client-side scripting only. You still need server-side codes to insert data into DB.

Comment: Actually, my db shema or server-side codes do not be used because I am not looking for the exact codes. I just need to find out how I can save data which come from JS codes. Although, I am not expert and if you guide me, I can explain myself better.

Comment: the main idea is, in JavaScript, make an AJAX POST call to your ASP.NET page, passing necessary data. The ASP.NET script will handle the data entry to DB.